# Variable in Python not being written to file after being defined by a Tkinter button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

So hello everyone. I have this problem with a GUI I'm making using Tkinter (Python module). So that is, I assign a command to the button, which is a function containing the things the program should do after clicking that button, and the command is simply to, when the button is pressed, change a variable. Well, that went fine just changing it, but when I tried to concatonate that value to a string to further be written into a file, it simply doesnt work. Here is the code.

```
import os
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

gui = ""
_path = ""

def ButtonA_command():
    gui = " -w"
    print(gui)

def ButtonB_command():
    gui = " "
    print(gui)

def ButtonC_command():
    bat_file = open("fatty.bat", "w")
    bat_file.write("pyinstaller --onefile" + gui + " " + EntryA.get())
    bat_file.close()
    
    



ButtonA = Button(root, text= "GUI", command= ButtonA_command)
ButtonB = Button(root, text= "CMD e GUI", command= ButtonB_command)
ButtonC = Button(root, text= "Criar", command= ButtonC_command)

EntryA = Entry(root)


ButtonA.pack()
ButtonB.pack()

EntryA.pack()

ButtonC.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly don't work? Concatenation or Writing File?

Comment: i dont know what doesnt work. All I know is that when I go to see the file I wanted to create, the variable value simply isnt there

Comment: It seems to work to me. It writes the value (EntryA.get()) concatenated

Comment: Is it that the program seems to work fine but you can't find the file later? It could be your current working directory.

Comment: I think I found whats the problem! You first click ButtonA then ButtonB and then ButtonC right?

Comment: No, I click ButtonA then ButtonC thats it

Comment: Are you running the program from the command line? If not, try that. It may display errors you arent' seeing otherwise. Also, you could `import tkinter.messagebox ` and `import os`, then `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title=None, message=os.getcwd())` to see where your file is written.

Comment: @tdelaney I can find the file easiily and read it, but it simply does not ouput the variable "gui" to the file.

Comment: Just make a correction in `ButtonB_command()`, instead of `gui = " "`, write `gui += " "`

Comment: `ButtonA_command` and `ButtonB_command` should both start with `global gui` so that they write the module-global variable, not a local variable called `gui` which is then discarded on exit.

Comment: @tdelaney didnt work to run it from cmd

Comment: @Yash - that doesn't work because `gui` as a local variable isn't initialized to anything. This is one of those cases where you need `global`

Comment: @ClashLarincoGamer - I was trying to determine what "simply doesn't work" means. Since we now know that the problem is that the global `gui` isn't being updated, the solution is the `global gui` declaration in the methods that update it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your functions as following. Otherwise, you are creating a local variable `gui` inside the scope of the function:

```
def ButtonA_command():
    global gui
    gui = " -w"
    print(gui)

def ButtonB_command():
    global gui
    gui = " "
    print(gui)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what is happening here. When you run ButtonA_command() a new variable called gui appears (so you have two variables called gui - one in your function and one outside of it). Use `global gui` as the first line of each function and it should work (does work on my pc).
Edit: other commenter was a bit faster :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write:

```
global gui
```

inside any function otherwise, it will treat it as a new local variable of that function.